# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `settings`) (View: Projects/code/public_html/resources/views/index.blade.php)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, composer, artisan

Обновил по инструкции Laravel с 5.4 до 8 версии, и при команде php artisan serve, есть ошибки,не знаю стоит ли чинить потому что на хостинге все работает хорошо, менял только composer.json[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        "anlutro/l4-settings": "^1.1.1",
        "hesto/multi-auth": "^1.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^10.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^5.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.0",
        "mjaschen/phpgeo": "^1.3",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^4.4",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-develop"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "composer/composer": "^1.10",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "laravel/browser-kit-testing": "1.*",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Helper/ControllerHelper.php",
            "app/Helper/ViewHelper.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "kylekatarnls/update-helper": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EoeXCif   мой файл env и ошибка при команде php artisan migrate

Comment: Скорее всего на localhost у вас не поднята база, либо поднята на другом порте\

Comment: теперь уже пишет доступ запрещен) https://imgur.com/a/pWm72tI